# Please lower the threshold for the brown review number to 1

Tags: feature-request, design, review-page

The brown number appears next to the review button in the top bar only if there are at least 3 items to review. **I would pretty much prefer to show this brown button whenever there is at least 1 item to review**<sup>1</sup>**.**

Why? We do not get so much traffic as other sites, and we do want to get more people involved in the review process. Currently, we have probably got some people who (I suppose by a script) "click F5 every second on https://tex.stackexchange.com/review to know about any new reviews as soon as possible". While I don't mind them doing it<sup>2</sup>, I think it would be healthy for the community if this got changed.

A second thing is, especially in First Posts, Low Quality and Reopen queues, it makes the best sense to act on the posts quickly; since the queues are empty almost all the time, this is not the case: Users do not notice there's something to review until there's at least 3 things to review.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm sorry, I don't provide a screenshot, there's currently only 1 item in the queue and the button is therefore not shown. 
<sup>2</sup> Given their reviews are of very high quality.

Comment: I rarely use the brown(?) marker as an indication that there is something to review.

Comment: I want this stupid review system gone. Or that the reviews are not open if there are not at least 100 items so that they cannot close every question at their pleasure. And we can answer some questions by taking our time. .

Comment: @percusse: That is specific to closure. Admittedly I've been suggesting duplicates lately which may not have been closed as such. But then again, it's just a vote and other can disagree. If you ever happen on a question that is closed (and shouldn't be) and you want to answer it, I suggest you write up an answer (to get ahead of the game), then request opening in the chat room. There's plenty of votes (and mods) to go around there.

Comment: @Werner Why do we keep adjusting our behaviors to a bunch weirdos instead of the other way around? I don't understand why we gave in so quickly to this review nonsense? You know much better than me how people were whizzing around the questions to answer them before